# Rails Ajax render partial with local variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

Hey I am trying to render a partial using ajax everything work in rails normal form but when I am rendering a partial using ajax local variables don't work I am trying to create a like and dislike system for that I have created a model called FeedLike here I can like and dislike using simple create and destroy but when I am using ajax and there I am calling this action below :

```
$('#feed_like').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/dislike', :locals => { feed: @feed= @feed} %>");
```

I am getting the error No route matches

`{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"feed_likes", :feed_id=>nil, :user_id=>1}`

And my dislike link  is like this  it is a partial which is under :

```
 <div id="feed_dislike">
    <%= link_to "Dislike",{ :action => 'destroy', :controller => 'feed_likes', :feed_id => @feed, :user_id => current_user.id }, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        </div>
```

everything work fine when I am not using ajax but when I am rendering partial why @feed is not getting any value what am I supposed to do . To get the value of feed.id . feed.id is coming from and model called Feed and it is under look  and there I am rendering these two forms using partials .

now I am pasting some codes which will give you what I am doing :

```
     #shared/_feed.html.erb
    <% if @feed_items.try(:any?) %>  
        <ol class="microposts">
            <%= render @feed_items %>

          </ol>
          <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
        <% end %>
```

And  @feed_items is coming from :

```
      #feeds/_feed.html.erb
     <li id="feed-<%= feed.id %>">
      <%= image_tag(current_user.avatar.url(:thumb), :size => '50x50') %>
      <span class="user"><%= link_to feed.user.name, feed.user %></span>
      <span class="content"><%= feed.content %></span>
      <span class="timestamp">
        Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(feed.created_at) %> ago.
      </span>

      <%  @like =FeedLike.where(:user_id => "#{current_user.id}", :feed_id => "#{feed.id}")
        %>


    <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_like', locals: { feed: @feed= feed.id} %>
    </li>
```

And now feed_like partial :

```
    #shared/_feed_like.html.erb
   <% if @like.count == 0 %> 

              <%= render :partial => 'shared/like', locals: { feed1: @feed= @feed} %>

              <% else %>

           <%= render :partial => 'shared/dislike', locals: { feed:  @feed} %>
            <% end %>
```

Controllers code for :

```
     class FeedsController < ApplicationController

            before_action :authenticate_user! ,only: [:create, :destroy]
          def create
              @feed = current_user.feeds.build(feed_params)
              @feed_likes = FeedLike.new
              if @feed.save
                 #redirect_to root_url
                respond_to do |format|

                format.html { redirect_to root_url }
                format.js
              end
               else
              respond_to do |format|

                format.html { redirect_to root_url }
                format.js { render :js=>'alert("you can not leave post empty");' }
              end
            end
            end

            def destroy
            end

            private

              def feed_params
                params.require(:feed).permit(:content)
              end
          end
```

FeedsLike controller :

```
                class FeedLikesController < ApplicationController
            before_action :authenticate_user! ,only: [:create, :destroy]

              def index
                @fees = FeedLike.all
                respond_to do |format|

                        format.html 
                        format.js


                        end
              end
            def update
                @feed_likes = FeedLike.find_or_create_by(feed_like_params)
                    respond_to do |format|
                        if @feed_likes.save
                        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Like ' }

                        else

                        end
                   end
            end
              def create
                    @feed_likes = FeedLike.find_or_create_by(:feed_id => params[:feed_id],:user_id =>params[:user_id])
                    respond_to do |format|
                        if @feed_likes.save
                        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Like ' }
                        format.js
                        else

                        end
                   end
              end


              def delete

              end

              def destroy
                  @feed_likes = FeedLike.where(:feed_id => params[:feed_id],:user_id =>params[:user_id])
                   respond_to do |format|
                       if @feed_likes.destroy_all
                       format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Unlike ' }
                       else

                       end
                   end
              end
              def feed_like_params
                  params.require(:feed_like).permit(:user_id, :feed_id)
                  #params[:market_place]
                end


              end
```

And staticpage controller :

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
                before_action :authenticate_user!
              def home

             if user_signed_in?
                 @feed_likes = current_user.feed_likes.new
                 @feed  = current_user.feeds.build
                 @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
                 # @likes = Feed.find(:all, 
                 #    :select => '"feeds".id, "feeds".content, count("feed_likes".id) as Like', 
                 #    :from => :feeds, 
                 #    :left_join => '"feed_likes"', 
                 #    :on => '"feeds".id = "feed_likes"."feed".id', 
                 #    :limit => 5
                 #  )

                 # @like =Feed.find_by_sql "

                 #        SELECT id
                 #        FROM feed_likes
                 #        WHERE user_id = #{current_user.id}
                 #        AND feed_id =#{feed.id}
                 #        LIMIT 0 , 30

                 #    "
                end
              end

              def help
              end


              def about
              end

             def contact
             end


            end
```

Comment: try this `$('#feed_like').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/dislike', :locals => { feed: @feed} %>");`

Comment: I had tried this but not working

Comment: is this the `$('#feed_like').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/dislike', :locals => { feed: @feed} %>");` the response for action in feed_likes controller. is your @feed object really exists in the file.?

Comment: No it is coming form <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_like', locals: { feed: @feed= feed.id} %>  location #feeds/_feed.html.erb

Comment: I was talking about after controller action.which controller action is this response

Comment: Feed_Likes controller @feed object  is   <%= render :partial => 'shared/feed_like', locals: { feed: @feed= feed.id} %> location #feeds/_feed.html.erb

Comment: Your @feed object is nil I think. Try to make do `@feed= Feed.find(params[:feed_id])` in the feed_likes controller create action

Comment: Ya it is working if you don't mind can you explain this is proper answer. I am unable to understand why it is under feedcontroller action

Comment: one more thing which method I should follow in ajax after adding @feed in controller it is working but for only one post it is not working for post it work only after refresh

Comment: okay regarding first thing. yes that was correct way. you are sending feed as params but you are not fetching in controller that is why it was nil. which you did now

Comment: second question i didnt get.

Comment: Hey you can see my codes I am trying to create a like and dislike system here on home page when I click like button it works for only one feed but when I am clicking on the next feed like button nothing happen in background it update the table but not rendering happen

Comment: And please post a proper answer to this question so that I can mark it as true

Comment: im not sure as i cant see the code. but im guessing bcoz you are putting the html code in the `$('#feed_like')` where feed_like is id. try to make it class and i would suggest to make it like this `$(".feed-like-<%= @feed.id %>")`. also please change your div where you put html after like and dislike to have seperate classes by appending id to the class. this will help you do it for all likes(PS: im not sure. this is just a wild guess)

Comment: I did not get your point

Comment: just like you did this `<li id="feed-<%= feed.id %>">` make the feed_like div to be this `<div id="feed_like-<%= feed.id%>"`  and in create.js do this $(".feed-like-<%= @feed.id %>").html.....  so that you will replace only that div with html. i hope this makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your feed is nil which is why it is crashing

please add this in your feed_likes controller.

```
before_action :get_feed ,only: [:create, :destroy]
```

and at the bottom add this method

```
def get_feed
  @feed= Feed.find(params[:feed_id])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your feed definition looks wrong in your javascript file. Try this instead:

```
$('#feed_like').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/dislike', :locals => { feed: @feed} %>");
```

Comment: Added controller details